# The tangent space of the space of all Riemannian metrics of volume 1

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tangent-spaces

Let $(M,g)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold and $\mathcal{M}$ be the set of all Riemannian metrics on $M$. How does one show that

$$
T_g\mathcal{M}_1 = \left\{h\in\Gamma(\mathrm{Sym}^2M)\mid\int_M\mathrm{tr}_g(h)\mathrm{vol}_g=0\right\}
$$
where $\mathcal{M}_1 = \{g\in\mathcal{M}\mid\int_M\mathrm{vol}_g=1\}$? (see for example A. Besse "Einstein Manifolds", p.118)

Edit: Maybe it is easier to show that $\mathcal{M}_1\subset\mathcal{M}$ is a submanifold of codimension 1? I currently have no approach to the solution of this. But if one could show this, the statement follows easily...

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: Well by the variation of the volume element its easy to show that at least $T_g\mathcal{M}_1\subseteq\{h\in\Gamma(\mathrm{Sym}^2M)\mid\int_M\mathrm{tr}_g(h)\mathrm{vol}_g=0\}$.

Comment: One just chooses some $h\in\Gamma(\mathrm{Sym}^2M)$ such that $g+th\in\mathcal{M}_1$ for $|t|<\varepsilon$. Thus we have $\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\right|_{t=0}\int_M\mathrm{vol}_{g+th}=0$. Since $\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\right|_{t=0}\mathrm{vol}_{g+th} = \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}_g(h)\mathrm{vol}_g$, the inclusion from the comment above follows directly.

Comment: I currently fail to see the reverse inclusion.

Comment: @Deane but how should one go about this? I do not see a way to properly solve for c...

Comment: I have seen (in some other literature - K.Kroencke "Stability of Einstein Manifolds") that $\mathcal{M}_1\subset\mathcal{M}$ is a submanifold of codimension 1. Perhaps it is somehow easier to show this?

Comment: The statement should then easily follow from this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given any metric $g$ such that $V_g(M) = 1$, let $g_t$ be any smooth $1$-parameter family of metrics such that
$$ g_0 = g\text{ and }\left.\partial_tg_t\right|_{t=0} = h.$$
Let
$$
V_t = V_{g_t}(M)
$$
and
$$
\hat{g}_t = V_t^{-1/n}g_t.
$$
It is now straightforward to show that $V_{\hat{g}_t}(M) = 1$ and
$$
\left.\partial_t\hat{g}_t\right|_{t=0} = h.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think it should be $\hat{g}_t = V_t^{-\frac{2}{n}}g_t$. Everything else seems fine.

Comment: Thanks for the correction.